# Сглаживание при масштабировании

Tags: canvas, html, html5

Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении масштаба (увеличении), текст, выведенный на `canvas` (HTML5), сглаживался. Как включить этот anti-aliasing? Тестировал в Хроме, по умолчанию ничего не сглаживается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, необходимость `antialiasing` на `canvas'e` - это решение, принимаемое на стороне браузера, а не клиентского кода. *Т.е, некоторые мобильные девайсы для повышения производительности в любом случае будут рисовать текст без сглаживания.*

---

Для отрисовки сглаженного текста даже при масштабировании необходимо руками изменять размер `canvas` и соответствующим образом производить перерисовку.

Главным параметром, на который необходимо опираться, для вас будет `window.devicePixelRatio`, более подробно *(и с кодом)* можно посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://joubert.posterous.com/crisp-html-5-canvas-text-on-mobile-phones-and)